# Intent filter to open playlist from browser in my application

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I thought I my app has all the possible filters, but still when I click:

http://www.swissgroove.ch/listen.php

in either Chrome or FireFox for Android, they start downloading the file in from the link (SwissGroove.m3u) instead of poping up window asking to choose which app should be used to open it. So the CORRECTED question is - how would you define an intentfilter in manifest that would allow opening any link CONTAINING either m3u or pls (but not looking like it, like in case of listen.php) in external app instead of downloading it?

Note: currently I have this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="rtmp" />
            <data android:scheme="rtmpe" />
            <data android:scheme="rtmps" />
            <data android:scheme="rtp" />
            <data android:scheme="rtsp" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsh" />
            <data android:scheme="icyx" />
            <data android:scheme="httplive" />
            <data android:scheme="udp" />
            <data android:scheme="vlc" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- This filter captures protocols with type info -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:scheme="rtmp" />
            <data android:scheme="rtmpe" />
            <data android:scheme="rtmps" />
            <data android:scheme="rtp" />
            <data android:scheme="rtsp" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsh" />
            <data android:scheme="icyx" />
            <data android:scheme="httplive" />
            <data android:scheme="udp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="ftp" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/rmvb" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/avi" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/mkv" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/3gpp*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/mp4" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/mpeg*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.3gp*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.rn-realmedia*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-extension-mp4" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-flac" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-matroska" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-mpegURL" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-quicktimeplayer" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/xspf+xml" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-winamp-playlist" />
            <data android:mimeType="misc/ultravox" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="ftp" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.3ga" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.a52" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.aac" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.ac3" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.adt" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.adts" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.aif" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.aifc" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.aiff" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.amr" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.aob" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.ape" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.awb" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.caf" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.dts" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.flac" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.it" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.m4a" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.m4b" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.m4p" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mid" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mka" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mlp" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mod" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mpa" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mp1" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mp2" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mp3" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mpc" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mpga" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.oga" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.ogg" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.oma" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.opus" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.ra" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.ram" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.rmi" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.s3m" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.spx" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.tta" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.voc" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.vqf" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.w64" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.wav" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.wma" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.wv" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.xa" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.xm" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.3GA" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.A52" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.AAC" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.AC3" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.ADT" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.ADTS" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.AIF" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.AIFC" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.AIFF" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.AMR" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.AOB" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.APE" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.AWB" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.CAF" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.DTS" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.FLAC" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.IT" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.M4A" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.M4B" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.M4P" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.MID" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.MKA" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.MLP" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.MOD" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.MPA" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.MP1" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.MP2" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.MP3" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.MPC" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.MPGA" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.OGA" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.OGG" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.OMA" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.OPUS" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.RA" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.RAM" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.RMI" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.S3M" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.SPX" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.TTA" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.VOC" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.VQF" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.W64" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.WAV" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.WMA" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.WV" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.XA" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.XM" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

To intercept the exact url http://www.swissgroove.ch/listen.php you can use this `intent-filter`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data
        android:host="www.swissgroove.ch"
        android:pathPrefix="/listen.php"
        android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

If you want to intercept every url of the domain http://www.swissgroove.ch/ you can use this `intent-filter`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data
        android:host="www.swissgroove.ch"
        android:pathPrefix="/"
        android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Well, yes. That's obvious. But what about playing any m3u/pls from any address that ends with different extension, like in this case? Does it mean that Android isn't able to check attachment header of http://www.swissgroove.ch/listen.php, so just happily assumes it's a php script? "It's impossible" is an acceptable answer :)